# ODS output in loop SAS

Tags: macros, sas

I am trying to output the compare result to excel or pdf for all the output from the library. here is what I wrote

```
%DO  I = 1 %TO &coun; 
%LET DT = %SCAN (&DS_LIST., &I., ~); 

ods excel file="D:\test.xlsx";

PROC COMPARE BASE = BASE.&DT. COMPARE = COMPARE.&DT. OUTNOEQUAL OUTBASE
 OUTCOMP OUT = COMPAREOUT; 
RUN
;  
ods excel close;
```

however it gives me only the last dataset output.. what is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not shown the `%END` for the `%DO` loop.  I would presume you are opening and closing the ODS EXCEL destination inside the loop.  ODS EXCEL does not append to an existing file, so you are only getting the comparison output from the last data set in the list.  Try this

```
* open ODS destination;
ods excel file="D:\test.xlsx";

* loop over data sets in DS_LIST, get compare report for each;
%DO  I = 1 %TO &coun;
  %LET DT = %SCAN (&DS_LIST., &I., ~); 

  PROC COMPARE BASE = BASE.&DT. COMPARE = COMPARE.&DT. OUTNOEQUAL OUTBASE
   OUTCOMP OUT = COMPAREOUT; 
  RUN;  
%END;

* close the ODS destination that contains the output from &coun comparisons;
ods excel close;
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried loading your excel file as a library? That way you could use proc compare directly...

```
LIBNAME xdbsss EXCEL PATH="<path and file>.XLSX" SCAN_TEXT=NO;
```

Comment: Excel is being used as the output destination here, not being read in or anything. Using libname doesn't make sense to pipe results there from PROC COMPARE because the tables don't align well to the output.

Comment: In case you don't know, using it as a libname also allows you to output in it!

Comment: ODS output is not automatically sent to a libname the way it is with an ODS statement. This solution will not solve the OPs problem.